# How to populate an array in javascript if I want to have multiple elements for a single index of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to populate an array in javascript when I want to store multiple elements in a single index?

I want to populate an array in Javascript. What I am trying to do is to store both firstName and lastName of a person in an array index. I am trying to do person[0].firstName = 'Dilshadur'; and then person[0].secondName = 'Rahman'; but It's not working and I think this is not the correct syntax to do so.

`person[0].firstName.fill('Md Dilshadur Rahman');
 person[0].lastName = 'Rahman';
 person[1].firstName = 'Tabassum Monia';
 person[1].lastName = 'Disha';`

I am getting in the console something like this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName'", I think this because of the wrong syntax and I am not being able to find the correct syntax.

Comment: Can you share what the existing item looks stored in the `person` array looks like?

Comment: Add an object there first `person[0] = {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to have an *object* assigned to each index of the array, and *each of those objects* would have the `firstName` and `lastName` properties.

Ex:

```
let person = [];
person[0] = {firstName: 'Dilshadur', lastName: 'Rahman'};
person[1] = {firstName: 'Tabassum Monia', lastName: 'Disha'};
```

You should consider creating a separate class or something where this structure is defined.

```
class Person {
    constructor(first, last) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
    }
}

let person = [];
person[0] = new Person('Dilshadur', 'Rahman');
person[1] = new Person('Tabassum Monia', 'Disha');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store an array of objects in that case.

```
const results = [
   { firstName: 'clark', lastName: 'kent' },
   { firstName: 'bruce', lastName: 'wayne' }
]
```

You can then use the `spread` operator to populate the entire index.

```
const newResults = [
   { firstName: 'peter', lastName: 'parker' },
   ...results
]
```

You can also push to your array, however it is good practice to not mutate your data and instead create an updated copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create array of objects

```
  person = [];
  person[0] = { firstName: "abc" , lastName: "def" } :

  Or you can push values to it by 
  person.push( { firstName: "abc" , lastName: "def" } )
```